# WARNING: Failed to register object with name [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/http:]]

Tags: java, tomcat7

tomcat server carsh after start of 2-3 days,
here is log -

> WARNING: Failed to register object
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/http:]]
>   with name
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/http:]]
>   during component initialisation
>   javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':'
>   in value part of property     at
>   javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:618)    at
>   javax.management.ObjectName.(ObjectName.java:1382)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.java:1084)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6506)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Jun 28, 2015 9:01:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   resourcesStart SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
>   javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':'
>   in value part of property     at
>   javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:618)    at
>   javax.management.ObjectName.(ObjectName.java:1382)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Jun 28, 2015 9:01:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   addChildInternal SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/http:]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5295)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 10 more
>
> Jun 28, 2015 9:01:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig
>   deployDirectory SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory
>   /opt/tomcat/webapps/http: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/http:]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I quoted the log messages to make it easier to read.   There is still a lot more to be done editing this.  Please explain more about your application, and what you think is happening.   What have you tried to resolve this?   Just dumping a long into a "question" isn't going to get you very far.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason there's a `/opt/tomcat/webapps/http:` directory created, which Tomcat then attempts to deploy as a web application, crashing due to the illegal character.

I suggest checking out the directory contents, the creation time should be right before the crash, check out the permissions of the directory (was it created by tomcat?).

If you have deployed webapps that can create directories during normal usage, check that there's not a security breach (i.e. you're not creating directories according to user input for example).